# How to create a HashTable in C# with multiple keys and values

Tags: c#, arrays, hashtable

I need to implement in C# the following structure from ActionScript3:

```
objectArray.push({name:"Stx10",category:123 , isSet:false, isEmpty:true});
```

So that later I can access the objects from the array like this:

```
String name =objectArray[i].name
```

So I naturally though about C Sharp Hash Tables but the allow only a single Key -> Value insertion. I can't believe .NET framework has not solution for such a thing...
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if HashTable is the best container to use, have you looked at Dictionary<key, value>?

Comment: Hashtables also support exactly what you tried to do (apart from not casting object -> String). Are you sure you didn't use a HashSet?

Comment: What kind of values do you store in the index variable `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're pushing a custom type to an array.

Using an IList will give you a quick Add method in which you can pass a new object of you type such as:

```
IList<MyType> myCollection = new List<MyType>();

myCollection.Add(new MyType{
Name = "foo",
Category = "bar",
IsSrt = true,
IsEmpty = true
});
```

**UPDATE**

Just to add a bit of extra value based on Henk's comment on Porges's answer, here's a way to do the same thing using a dynamic type and thus removing the need for a custom type:

```
IList<dynamic> myCollection  = new List<dynamic>();
    myCollection.Add(new {  
      Name = "foo",
      Category = "bar",
      IsSet = true,
      IsEmpty = true});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie and @Porges for your answers !

Comment: You're welcome Michael. I've just also added an update on using a dynamic list.

Comment: Wow that is awesome Jamie.I really was more interested in a dynamic solution because in my case the parameters vary.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well ,I work with MONO (Unity3D)and it seems that MONO C Sharp doesn't support <dynamic>.Too bad .Will have to stick to your previous solutions.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just accessing elements by index as in your example, then you don't need hashed access, you can just use a `List<T>`.

I'd encapsulate your information into a type like this:

```
class Thing {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Category {get; set;}
    public bool IsSet {get; set;}
    public bool IsEmpty {get; set;}
}
```

Then:

```
objectList.Add(new Thing{Name="Stx10", Category=123, IsSet=false, IsEmpty=true})

// ...

string name = objectList[i].Name;
```

Comment: And an anonymous/dynamic type to hold `name` , `category` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about

```
  var d=new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

What's your intention though?